# metafor forest plot aggregated values

Tags: r, multi-level, r-forestplot, metafor

First time posting.

I've run a multi-level m-a in metafor, and like Wolfgang's idea of creating a forest plot to show an aggregate effect size for each study  (so, say, an m-a of 100 studies, some of which have a single effect, some have 5 effects, some have 10, but the forest plot would show only a single effect for each study). The tutorial (here:https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:forest_plot_with_aggregated_values) is v clear, and I've used it for my own data.

What I cannot do, however, is make the titles of studies in my first plot appear as author's names, instead of appearing as 'Study 1', 'Study 2', etc.

Can someone guide me how to add that info (i.e., author name, presumably in an extra column that I am failing to include when I am running the aggregate function) to the aggregate data or 'escalc' object, please?

So, here is the code I used:

#call data
data_RR<- read.csv("MA_RR_Data.csv")
#create a subset
data_RR<- subset(data_RR, pool==1)
#create an escalc object
dat <- escalc(measure = "RR", ai = bi_anx, bi = bi_not_anx, ci = not_bi_anx, di = not_bi_not_anx, data = data_RR, append = TRUE, add = 1/2, to = "only0", slab=paste("Study", First_Author, "Estimate", es.id, "obs", Obs))

#### assume that the effect sizes within studies are correlated with rho=0.8

V <- vcalc(vi, cluster=Paper.ID, obs=es.id, data=dat, rho=0.8)

#### fit multilevel model using this approximate V matrix

res <- rma.mv(yi, V, random = ~ 1 | First_Author/es.id, data=dat, digits=3)
res

#aggregate data from within studies
agg <- aggregate(dat, cluster=First_Author, V=vcov(res, type="obs"), addk=TRUE)
#limit 'agg' to columns with headings: First_Author (2), yi (42), vi (43), ki (44)
agg <- agg[c(2 42, 43, 44)]
agg
#meta-analyses pooled estimates
res <- rma(yi, vi, method="EE", data=agg, digits=3)
res
#draw a forest plot
forest(res, xlim=c(-4,5), mlab="Pooled Estimate", header=TRUE, ilab=ki, ilab.xpos=-2)

All the best,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHVi1.png)Pete

PS I know the formatting of the features of the plot are sloppy, but I can solve that part by fiddling with distances once I have the author names in place!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `slab` argument again, this time as part of `rma()` when fitting the model to the aggregated data (e.g., `rma(yi, vi, method="EE", data=agg, digits=3, slab=First_Author`).